Automatically aligning Roman numerals with other text within the document
I began typing my pdf file using overleaf. The material I have consists of Math MCQs. I faced many problem and decided not to continue typing before I fix these things first.
However, as commented in that post, it will be easier when I ask one question per post, and I totally agreed. For that I am posting this.
In that post, first problem (out of the five problems) has been solved here by David Carlisle. His answer is really awesome, it did what I want.
Now we come to the next problem, which is aligning Roman numerals with other text within the document.

Issue:
Some of my MCQs have items, numbered with Roman numbers, where the leftmost character is not in the required position.
Requirement:
For those MCQs which have Roman numerals, the leftmost character in Roman numeral must be aligned directly above the content of answer choice (A), not above "(A)".

For example:

On the left, Roman numbers are (almost) above (A), I need to place them (automatically), as shown on the right. To be exact, the leftmost character should be above the content of answer choice (A).
In case we have I, II, III, IV, V for example, then we need to consider the III, because it is the longest one, not the V.

My current code is:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\np}{%
  \par%
  \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{Problem \theproblem:}\par
}
\newcommand{\ep}{\par\noindent\hrulefill}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{anslist}{O{}b}
{%
  \sbox0{\begin{enumerate*}[#1]#2\end{enumerate*}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]#2\end{enumerate}
  \else
    \par\noindent\usebox{0}\par
  \fi
}
{}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\np 
If $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$, what is the value of $f'(0)$?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $0$
  \item $1$
  \item $\sqrt{2}$
  \item $2$
  \item $\pi$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Suppose that $f$ is a function on the interval $[1,3]$ such that $-1\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. How large can $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ be?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $8$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\log(2)$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets, and let $f:A\xrightarrow{}B$ and $g:B\xrightarrow{}C$ be functions. Which of the following is true?
\begin{anslist}[label=\Roman*.,leftmargin=*]
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
    \item If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective, then $f\,\circ\,g$ is identically zero.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g=g\,\circ\,f$, then both $f$ and $g$ cannot be simultaneously bijective.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g$ is injective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ can be either $0$ or $1$.
\end{anslist}
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item I and II only
  \item I and III only
  \item II and III only
  \item III only
  \item III, IV, V and VI only
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the solid generated?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
  \item $\pi$
  \item $2\pi$
  \item $\infty$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x^2y-x$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Which of the following is true of $f$?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item There is an absolute minimum at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a relative maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a saddle point at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item There is an absolute maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item All critical values are on the line $y=x$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Find the general solution of
$$\displaystyle2\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+9\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-35y=0$$
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{\frac{5}{2}x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{5x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-5x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos(5x)+C_2\cos(7x)$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Suppose today is Wednesday. What day of the week will it be $\displaystyle 10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item Sunday
   \item Monday
   \item Tuesday
   \item Wednesday
   \item Thursday
\end{anslist}
\ep

\end{document}


I saw (exam), but for me it was not helpful. I am not saying it is bad, but I am a new user and it looks so advanced for me. Probably it will be beneficial for me in future when I get some more basic things with LaTex.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Roman numberls take up more space, so enumitem automatically gives it more space. (right aligned).  You could achieve the effect on the right by skipping a level.

This nests two levels of anslist.  Note that the roman numerals have additional space available in the label, which is aligned to the text in the outer list.
BTW, did you really have to include all that other code in your MWE?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\np}{%
  \par%
  \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{Problem \theproblem:}\par
}
\newcommand{\ep}{\par\noindent\hrulefill}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{anslist}{O{}b}
{%
  \sbox0{\begin{enumerate*}[#1]#2\end{enumerate*}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]#2\end{enumerate}
  \else
    \par\noindent\usebox{0}\par
  \fi
}
{}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\np 
If $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$, what is the value of $f'(0)$?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $0$
  \item $1$
  \item $\sqrt{2}$
  \item $2$
  \item $\pi$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Suppose that $f$ is a function on the interval $[1,3]$ such that $-1\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. How large can $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ be?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $8$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\log(2)$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets, and let $f:A\xrightarrow{}B$ and $g:B\xrightarrow{}C$ be functions. Which of the following is true?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \begin{anslist}[label=\Roman*.,leftmargin=*]
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
    \item If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective, then $f\,\circ\,g$ is identically zero.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g=g\,\circ\,f$, then both $f$ and $g$ cannot be simultaneously bijective.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g$ is injective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ can be either $0$ or $1$.
  \end{anslist}
  \item I and II only
  \item I and III only
  \item II and III only
  \item III only
  \item III, IV, V and VI only
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the solid generated?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
  \item $\pi$
  \item $2\pi$
  \item $\infty$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x^2y-x$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Which of the following is true of $f$?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item There is an absolute minimum at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a relative maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a saddle point at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item There is an absolute maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item All critical values are on the line $y=x$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Find the general solution of
$$\displaystyle2\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+9\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-35y=0$$
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{\frac{5}{2}x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{5x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-5x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos(5x)+C_2\cos(7x)$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Suppose today is Wednesday. What day of the week will it be $\displaystyle 10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item Sunday
   \item Monday
   \item Tuesday
   \item Wednesday
   \item Thursday
\end{anslist}
\ep

\end{document}

